# onclick function works but onsubmit doesn't

Tags: javascript, onclick, onsubmit

I am trying to make a submit button that when it is clicked then the image will move and another button that when it is clicked the image will reset.

Somehow if I do it with `onclick` function and the image will move and things are good, but if I use it with `onsubmit` function then it wouldn't work.  Anyone can give me an idea why?

This is what I have for my script:

```
function catMoveRight()
{
    document.getElementById("cat").style.left=parseInt(document.getElementById("cat").style.left)+1+"px";
}

window.onload=function()
{
    catTimer = null;

    document.getElementById("start").onsubmit=function()
    {
        if(catTimer == null)
        {   
            catTimer = setInterval("catMoveRight()",1000);
        }

    }

}
```

This is my HTML `body`:

```
<img src="cat.jpg" id="cat" style=" position: absolute; left: 10px;"/><br/>
<form action=" " method="post" id="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Start" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 220px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: you need to show your code for the `onsubmit` and not for the `onclick`, you might bind event to an image instead of form or some other errors you might be missing.

Comment: `onsubmit` is only valid if you put it onto a `<form>`, not a button. You should use `onclick` for that.

Comment: Is the `onsubmit` added to the form?

Comment: editted my code to onsubmit instead of the onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to cancel the default action of the form submit. One way is to return `false` from the event handler:

```
document.getElementById("start").onsubmit = function()
{
    if(catTimer == null)
    {   
        catTimer = setInterval(catMoveRight, 1000);
    }
    return false;
};
```

Also there's no need to pass a string to `setInterval`. Don't use `eval` where it's not necessary.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QD3ev/1/

Comment: thanks.  I believe it's the return false; that I didn't add ^_^